# When we send messages to multiple numbers at atime, how to know for which number we are getting getResultCode()?

Tags: android

i am developing android sms application in which i send message to multiple numbers. i want to get resultant code for all numbers.When we send messages to multiple numbers at atime, how to know for which number we are getting getResultCode()?
is there any example code for this type of coding.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `requestCode` that is passed into `startActivityForResult()` to track the results for each invocation. When `onActivityResult()` is called, it will have the corresponding `requestCode` passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the phonenumber with the intent extras when sending SMS....and when u receive this intent take out the phone number from extras of intent which will help u indentify that this response is for SMS of which phone number..